# C++ Mersenne Twister and Random numbers lib

Tags: c++, random, mersenne-twister

I am migrating a large scientific simulation software to C++. In Java I used  [Cern Colt library](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/cern/jet/random/package-summary.html) and it included a complete list of random distributions.

What C++ library is normally used when different distributions (such as those listed on the provided link) are needed?

Smaller focused libraries are preferred (not like boost).

Thanks.

Comment: [C++11 contains some nice random number features, including a Mersenne twister.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) Unfortunately it doesn't contain as much as your link.

Comment: Boost is a collection of libraries, you don't need to include/link all of boost to use i.e. Boost.Random library, if you only use Boost.Random from boost, then only that will be included in your final product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[boost::random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) might be helpful to you.

Comment: The OP said `not like boost`, also boost random has been included in the standard library already (I think they provide the same random number distributions).

Comment: I finally used boost since I needed it in many other places too.